# how to get the first word in a string in excel

Tags: excel, vba

probably a very simple question, but I am trying to match words in excel

If a word is found on range A1:a400 then replace the word in a different workbook with the first word in that row

wkbk 1

a1 = sun      a200 = pear

pear is found

wkbk 2
a10 = sun (first word in row 1 in wbk 1)

this is all of course dynamic.  Thank you in advance

here is where this takes place

```
If Not word = " " Then ' if not blank
    If word = Cell.Value Then
        fixedWord = Cell.Value(at the first word of this row)
        workBookBeingChecked.Activate
        Cell.Value(foundWordRange) = fixedWord   ' cell in old place is replaced by this new cell
    End If
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: Sorry if the initial post was vague.  Not first word in a string, the string at the first cell of the row.  The method is searching a range a1:d600.  Lets say it matched a wors in cell c200.  How can i say, wherever you found the cell, go to the first cell in that row and make c200 the value of a200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amended to fit your updated question:

To get the first cell in a row based on a matched value use:

```
Range("C200").EntireRow.Columns(1).Value2
```

Comment: See above for further explanation